# NullPointerException during JSON Deserializtion in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I have a Space object for which I have written a custom serializer and deserializer. Now I have wrapped this object in a simple object for some context. What I would like to do is serialize/deserialize this wrapper.

My Space object serializes/deserializes fine. I just get the following exception when attempting to deserialize:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedParser.java:1477)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedParser.java:368)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:690)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
    at com.newoak.noc.curve.model.tests.ModelParamsTest.deserializeGraph(ModelParamsTest.java:100)
    at com.newoak.noc.curve.model.tests.ModelParamsTest.testSerializationDeserialization(ModelParamsTest.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
```

Here is where my exception is thrown:

```
public ModelParamGraph deserializeGraph(String json) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
        testModule.addSerializer(new SpaceJsonSerializer());
        testModule.addDeserializer(Space.class, new SpaceJsonDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(testModule);

        ModelParamGraph space = mapper.readValue(json, ModelParamGraph.class);

        return space;
    }
```

This is my wrapper:

```
public class ModelParamGraph implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6123736933251596579L;

@JsonSerialize(using=SpaceJsonSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using=SpaceJsonDeserializer.class)
public Space<TModelParam> paramSpace;

public String source;

public Date date;

private static Log log_ = LogFactory.getLog(ModelParamGraph.class);

public ModelParamGraph(){}

public ModelParamGraph(String source, Date date)
{
    setSource(source);
    setDate(date);

    log_.debug("Creating ModelParam Graph");
    setParamSpace(new Space<TModelParam>());
}

public Space<TModelParam> getParamSpace()
{
    return paramSpace;
}

public void setParamSpace(Space<TModelParam> paramSpace)
{
    this.paramSpace = paramSpace;
}

public void addParameter(TModelParam param, TModelParam parent)
{
    if (paramSpace.getRootData() == null)
    {
        paramSpace.addData(param, true);
    }
    else 
    {
        paramSpace.addData(param);
    }

    if (parent != null)
    {
        paramSpace.link(parent, param, "parent");
    }
}

public String getSource()
{
    return source;
}

public void setSource(String source)
{
    this.source = source;
}

public Date getDate()
{
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date)
{
    this.date = date;
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is `json` possibly `null`?

Comment: no, json is properly formatted json from a prior serialization

Comment: Ok, let's try to reproduce. Post the value of `json`, your `SpaceJsonSerializer` and `SpaceJsonDeserializer`.

Comment: The space itself serializes and deserializes fine but when it's part of this wrapper class i get the NullPointer Exception. Are there any rules around nested objects that require custom serializers/deserializers?

Comment: The wrapper also serializes fine, it just doesnt deserialize back

Comment: Download the jackson sources and try debugging to see what's up at that line.

Comment: I think it's more of a conceptual problem i'm having. How do you deal with the custom deserialization of nested classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not solve this problem. The NullPointer Exception is being thrown from within jackson. Sounds like it might be a bug on their end.